# Variables used in Test Package in R Studio

Tags: r

I am trying to fix an issue in an R project (that I'm not too familiar with). The test script that is executed when running "Test Package" in R-Studio uses a variable, let's call it x. From the result of the test I can tell that the data assigned to this variable is outdated and I want to update it.

Problem is, I just cannot figure out where this variable is actually defined. I have used grep for the entire source code of the package, and I only find the instance from the test script but no declaration. It is not defined in the script itself nor anywhere else in the source code.

When I just load the package, the variable is not defined. Somehow it is defined however when running the test, because only when I change the name in the test script into some dummy I get the error that it isn't defined.

Is there a specific place where I could look, or may be a simple trick how I could figure out where and how the variable is defined?

Thanks

Edit: the actual variable name is a bit complicated, it is not x

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, it'll be difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I understand but it is really only this, the variable is called but I don't see where it is defined. I am now trying to figure out what R-Studio does when I run "Test Package", because even if I run the testing script manually, the variable is never defined, so "Test Package" must somehow use more resources from elswehere that I cannot identify

Answer (score 1):

The `find in files` option in RStudio may help.

You can search through multiple files within a folder.

[image]

[image]

If you get too many matches to sort through (I'm really hoping your variable is not actually called `x`!), you can try using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ePE.png)

Follow the pictures and you could solve the problem.

Comment: please mention the package that you are using.